# Eclipse Memory Analyzer source

Tags: eclipse, open-source, eclipse-mat

Where is Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (http://eclipse.org/mat/) source code located? It is claimed to be open-source, but the site doesn't contain any download for the source code.

Comment: http://wiki.eclipse.org/MemoryAnalyzer/Contributor_Reference#Get_the_source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for http://git.eclipse.org/c/mat/org.eclipse.mat.git/refs/
I think you can download R_1.4.0.zip for the source code of the most recent version.
Here is the link for all eclipse git repositories btw http://git.eclipse.org/c/